# What is the difference between data validation and exception handling?

Tags: c#, error-handling, separation-of-concerns

My question, may be pretty basic, but I want to understand the core difference between data validation and exception handling, and **when you should use** both of them.

I was told by someone that you should never use exception handling in your code unless you absolutely have to because exceptions complicate your code. However, aren't try-catch-finally statements (exception handling) a good way to separate business logic and the UI? What are best practices when validating user input, and displaying error messages in the UI?

Comment: Can you please explain to me how you think try-catch statements separate business logic and UI? Also, this question is too broad, the only answer someone could really give you is "it depends."

Comment: My logic behind this was that in your business model you would have the try-catch statements, then if there was something invalid (exception occurred) you'd pass the message to the UI and display it to the user.

Comment: ths isn't the right place to ask since it isn't a specific problem you are having. Try here:  https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: DV checks if user inputs or imported data are valid to avoid exceotions; exception handling is ignoring that, then catching an exception later when using bad data (Null ref, Div Zero) and trying to figure out what went wrong and with what and why

Comment: Thank you, I'll post it on this site.

Comment: Data validation is where you check that the data which has been passed to a function is what is expected. Not necessarily just the data types, but the values.

Exceptions shouldn't be used for business logic - they are designed for error handling (exceptional circumstances). There can also be performance hits for handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data validation means checking the data before performing operations that could fail, for example check for 0 before doing a division.

Exception handling means well defined behavior if an operation fail, for example if a database query times out.

How to choose between the tow depends on what you are doing. While it is not elegant to use exception handling to catch a 0 devisor since you can easily check it before, you have to use exception handling on operations that communicates with other resources (database queries or TCP sockets will fail, or even disks will go out of space).

Comment: What are data validation best practices? I have done it before for school, but that was when I only had one class applications; now that I'm using more classes I want to create a validation class to perform all my data validations. What is the best way to present the info to the user if data is invalid?

Comment: If you are using classes to contain the data to be processed, you may implement an validate method in the class so the data and the business logic to validate data will be in same place.